# How do I save a message to database in consumers.py

Tags: python, django

I followed the channels documentation to create a chat app. I've created a Message model and a model form, but when I type in a message and click send, it responds accordingly but the message doesn't save to the database. I want the message to save when I click send.
I believe I'm supposed to write a save method in consumers.py but I'm not sure of how to do that.

**consumers.py**

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer

from .models import Message


class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
        # Join room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
        # Send message to room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        # Send message to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
                                        }))

    def save_message(self):
        ???
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save a message into the database from your consumer, then I think you can just do it in receive method:

```
def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
        message = Message.objects.create(content=message, user=self.scope["user"], room=self.room_name)
        ...
```

Comment: @AyzayPrince Make sure to mark this question as accepted if it solved your issue.